# How can i find the ETA of an event in javascript using simple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a javascript game and would like to display an ETA telling the user how long they have left until they lose the game. This figure is dependent on 3 variables,

```
var max = 1000000 /* 1 million */
var current = 50 /* 50 currently */
var persec = 10 /* 10 new ones created every second */
```

How using javascript can I calculate an estimate of the number of seconds till `current` >= `max` using the rate of change provided using `persec`?

**Things I have tried**

```
var eta = (max - current / persec) / 60;
    eta = Math.round(eta);
```

but this did not work as I am expecting it to.

Comment: A bit of a maths faux pas - `var eta = ((max - current) / persec) / 60;`  It was actually doing `max - (current / persec)`

Comment: if i set `persec` to 100, the ETA is 3 minutes, `but 100*60*3 != max`

Comment: With the correction I showed in the previous comment, I get 167 minutes if I set `persec` to 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple math mistake, missing parentheses. If you want to get the number of minutes, this formula will work:

```
    var eta = ((max - current) / persec) / 60;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BLeZX/

If, as your text says, you want the number of seconds instead, just omit the division by 60.

Comment: Oops, guess I was late (I only saw the identical answer as a comment to the question after I submitted this)!

I cannot comment up there due to a lack of reputation, but here's the explanation to the discrepancy between max and eta*60*3 that you noted: You're rounding eta. Without rounding, it should come close. In fact, within the bounds set by floating point precision, it should be identical.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and sorry that I am so bad at maths (terrible maths teachers are to blame)

Comment: Don't be sorry about that. It's an easy mistake to make.
Thanks for the upvotes---now I actually have enough reputation to make comments directly to a question!